# Namespace for redis-queue queue in django app

Tags: django, redis

I have a django app that uses redis-queue for managing long running tasks in the background. I have it set up and running (if in a stupid configuration), but I'm unclear what the appropriate namespace to store my queue is.

I set up the rq worker as recommended in the docs:

```
#rqsetup.py
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection


listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']
redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

I can add the queue to my view:

```
# views.py
from rqsetup import conn
from rq import Queue
from somewhere import bgtask

def myview(request):
    q = Queue(connection=conn)
    job = q.enqueue(bgtask)
    return render(request, 'somepage.html')
```

This is obviously dumb, because then the queue and the job are lost after the view is returned. The whole point is to have the queue in some namespace where I can access it again later.

However, I can't figure anywhere else to put it. If I try to in `rqsetup`, I just get import errors, or it imports out of order before its set up properly. I don't really have a good guess of where else it should go.

I otherwise have a normally structured app:

```
myproject
 -myproject
  -__init__.py
  -settings.py
  -urls.py
  -wsgi.py
 -myapp
  -apps.py
  -somewhere.py
  -views.py
 -manage.py
 -Procfile
 -requirements.txt
 -rqsetup.py
```

Where should a redis-queue queue be stored in a django project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `django_rq` [provides the queue namespace](https://github.com/rq/django-rq) for you! `settings.py` should have something like this:

```
RQ_QUEUES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 6379,
        'DB': 0,
        'PASSWORD': 'some-password',
        'DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 360,
    },
    'high': {
        'URL': os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0'), # If you're on Heroku
        'DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 500,
    },
    'low': {
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 6379,
        'DB': 0,
    }
}
```

Then you just just get the queue from the django_rq namespace: `queue = django_rq.get_queue('high')`.